# Oracle Date Rounding of Milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle

How does Oracle DB round milliseconds in its date function?

For example if `sysdate` is run at exactly "05/25/2012 01:15:25.900", would the date be stored as "05/25/2012 01:15:26" (rounding up) or as "05/25/2012 01:15:25" (rounding down)?

Does it round up for everything beyond half a millisecond, and down for everything lower than half a millisecond?

Here is a simple test I put together:

```
SELECT to_char(systimestamp, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss:ff') as sys_time_stamp,
to_char(
     TO_DATE (
         TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
         'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
     'dd-mm-yyy hh:mi:ss') as sys_date
FROM DUAL;
```

Run 1
sys_time_stamp: 25-05-2012 12:37:32:798000
sys_date: 25-05-012 12:37:32

Run 2
sys_time_stamp: 25-05-2012 12:43:41:322000
sys_date: 25-05-012 12:43:41

This would indicate that at least when converting a `systimestamp` to a `date` the milliseconds are just dropped. But when `sysdate` is actually generated, are milliseconds actually just dropped?

Comment: Have you tried any tests? We're not your personal search assistant.

Comment: How is `sysdate` ever going to be `05/25/2012 01:15:25.900`? `Sysdate` is of type `date` and only has second resolution.

Comment: They call that a 'date'?  That's a low-resolution timestamp...

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding the fractions of time up would result in the sysdate being on average half a second fast.

It would flip to the next day at 23:59:59.500.

This would obviously be idiotic, so I'm going to go with truncation rather than rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Since an Oracle `DATE` only stores a date to the second and `SYSDATE` relies on the underlying operating system's clock so I would expect the result to be operating system dependent.  Oracle is just calling out to the operating system asking "what is the date to the second" for `SYSDATE` and "what is the date to most precision you have" for `SYSTIMESTAMP`.  Since that call is inherently operating system dependent and the behavior isn't otherwise specified in the documentation, I would expect that different operating systems would or at least could have different implementations (technically, more likely it is the C library that the database kernel is compiled against on each operating system).

I would strongly suspect that the Oracle kernel is just calling the [C time function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/) for `SYSDATE` and the [C gettimeofday function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/High_002dResolution-Calendar.html) for `SYSTIMESTAMP` so whatever the library implementation happens to be is the behavior you'll get.